# TeamCity build configuration select based on package.json change

Tags: node.js, git, npm, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I'm using TeamCity for building my node project. My build configuration is triggered by a git commit, has several steps, and one of them is `npm install`.

What I want is for TeamCity to recognize if latest commit didn't make any changes to `package.json` file and in that case fire up a different build configuration - without `npm install` command.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Use a shell script and add it as a command line build step. If Else conditions should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [VCS trigger rules](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-VCSTriggerRules) to limit the changes that trigger the build.